# Custom draggable plugin wont work with touch events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got plugin for draggable interaction that uses 3dtransforms, but I can't figure out how to make it work with touch devices, I tried replacing all mousedown, mouseup, mousemove events to respectfull touchstart, touchend, rouchmove ones, and it seems to work as every time I drag console prints out NaN, nothing happens obviously, but it seems to recognize touch events, so I have no idea why it doesn't work. Example that works on desktop available here: https://jsfiddle.net/3orh783q/

(This is not using anything like jQuery UI, just jQuery)

```
$(document).ready(function() {  

    //Custum draggable functionality
    $.fn.draggable = function() {
      var $document = $(document)
        , mouse = { update: function(e) {this.x = e.pageX; this.y = e.pageY;} };

      return this.each(function(){
        var $elem = $(this);
        $elem.bind('mousedown.drag', function(e) {
          mouse.update(e);
          if ( !/^(relative|absolute)$/.test($elem.css('position') ) ) {
            $elem.css('position', 'relative');
          }
          $document.bind('mousemove.drag', function(e) {
            var translateX = (parseInt(getTranslate($elem, 'x'))||0) + (e.pageX - mouse.x),
                translateY = (parseInt(getTranslate($elem, 'y'))||0) +  (e.pageY - mouse.y);
            // $elem.css({
            //   left: (parseInt(getTranslate($elem, 'x'))||0) + (e.pageX - mouse.x) + 'px',
            //   top: (parseInt(getTranslate($elem, 'y'))||0) +  (e.pageY - mouse.y) + 'px'
            // });
            $elem.css({
                'transform': 'translate3d('+translateX+'px, '+translateY+'px, 0)',
                '-webkit-transform': 'translate3d('+translateX+'px, '+translateY+'px, 0)'
            });
            console.log(translateX);
            console.log(translateY);
            mouse.update(e);
            e.preventDefault();
          });
          $document.one('mouseup.drag', function(e) {
            $document.unbind('mousemove.drag');
          });
          e.preventDefault();
        });  
      });

        //Get current translate values
        function getTranslate(el, pos) {
            var translate = '',
                position = 0;

                // matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 3, 5)

            if(el.css('transform')) {
                translate = el.css('transform');
            }
            else if(el.css('-webkit-transform')) {
                translate = el.css('-webkit-transform');
            } else {
                translate = '';
            }

            var result = translate.match(/\d+/g).slice(-2);

            if(pos == 'x') {
                position = result[0];
            }
            else if(pos == 'y') {
                position = result[1];
            }

            return position;
        }
    }

    //Initialize dragable map
    $('.dragMe').draggable();

});
```

**EDIT**

After playing around it seems that pageX and pageY are not defined with touch devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mousemove, mousedown and mouseup doesn't works in touch devices. You must to change it with `touchmove`, `touchstart` and `touchend`.

You can make an object like this:

```
if(touch) {
    events['down'] = "touchstart";
    events['up'] = "touchend";
    events['move'] = "touchmove";
} else {
    events['down'] = "mousedown";
    events['up'] = "touchend";
    events['move'] = "touchmove";
}
```

When you need to use it:

```
$elem.bind(events['down'], function(e) {
     // your stuff
});
```

Comment: Alright this cleans up code a bit by providing accurate events based on device, in both cases they get recognised, but on touch devices element is still not moving around :/

Comment: My code is only an example. You can polyfill all events with this: http://vistaprint.github.io/SkinnyJS/docco/jquery.pointerEvents.html